# ASP.net Ajax Navigateaway JQuery issue

Tags: asp.net, jquery-plugins, asp.net-ajax

I am using the below mentioned jQuery scripts to alert users when they try to navigate before saving data.

[NavigateAway](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/NavigateAway.aspx?display=Mobile)

The problem I am having is the validation doesn't work for the buttons that are in updatePanel.
All the others work well.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you linked to, the way this plugin works is by subscribing to the [`onbeforeunload`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event.  I don't believe this event is triggered when UpdatePanel executes async requests.

Take a look at the example here of how to manually trigger the validation: [calling onbeforeunload from an updatepanel](http://forums.asp.net/t/1193634.aspx) *(note, code copied from the link provided)*.

```
function pageLoad() {
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
}

// This fires before the partial postback occurs
function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {
    // Call the validation function here, should be something like this
    handleOnBeforeUnload();
}
```